# Selectize from one column and pass values of another column

Tags: mysql, shiny, sqldf

I am trying to select multiple values from a column on MySQL and Shiny.
Some names with special characters do not return values when queried from a Mysql database.
How can I choose the names but pass to the query the geo instead of the names.

```
      library(shiny)
      library(dplyr)
      library(sqldf)
      library(DT)
      library(stringr)

       survey <- data.frame("name" = c("Oberösterreich", "Северозападен", "Κύπρος", "Strední Cechy", 
                 "Severovýchod", "Praha"),
                 "geo" = c("AT31", "BG31", "CY00", "    CZ02", "CZ05", "CZ01"),
                 "population" =c(100409314, 54086980, 30961705, 164741605, 156857074, 93166890))



          shinyApp(
             ui = fluidPage(
            fluidRow(
              wellPanel(
                  selectizeInput(
                                'Region',
                                label = "Region Select",
                                choices = NULL,
                                options = list(
                                 placeholder = 'Select Region',
                                 maxOptions = 1000,
                                 maxItems = 10,
                                 searchConjunction = 'and'
                                   )
                                    ))),
                          fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput('table')),
                                        ),
                         server = function(input, output, session){

                updateSelectizeInput(session,
                                "Region",
                                server = TRUE,
                                  choices = survey$`name`)

           geonamesdata <- reactive({
            SelectedRegion <-
          stringr::str_c(stringr::str_c("'", input$Region, "'"), collapse = ',')

        sqldf(paste0("
            SELECT DISTINCT c.name, c.geo 
            FROM survey c
                   WHERE c.name IN (",
                       SelectedRegion,
                       ")
     "))
})           
             
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(geonamesdata(),
                                     selection = 'single',
                                     options = list(searching = FALSE,pageLength = 10),
                                     server = FALSE, escape = FALSE,rownames= FALSE)      
             

  })
```

EDIT

I have come up with another demo to illustrate what I would want.

I have a MySQL database but for purposes of this question I will use SQLDF which is similar in syntax on Shiny environment.

```
    library(shiny)
    library(dplyr)
    library(sqldf)
    library(DT)
    library(stringr)

        df <- data.frame(empName = c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria"),
                        empID = c("J111", "B222", "M333"),
                         empAge = c(23, 41, 32),
                        empSalary = c(21000, 23400, 26800)
                        )


       shinyApp(

          ui = fluidPage(

                        selectizeInput("Search", label = p("Select name"), 
                              choices = as.character(df$empName),
                               multiple = TRUE),
                        hr(),
              fluidRow(
                  column(6, DT::dataTableOutput("table1")), 
                  column(6, DT::dataTableOutput("table2"))),
              hr(),
              hr(),
             fluidRow(
                    column(6, DT::dataTableOutput("table3")),
                         column(6, DT::dataTableOutput("table4"))
                     )),



          server = function(input, output, session) {  
               output$table1 = DT::renderDataTable({ df }, options = list(dom = 't'))
                  

            df2 <-  reactive ({ 
                (df %>% filter(empName %in% input$Search)%>% select(empID))  
                       })

          output$table2 = DT::renderDataTable({
                       req(input$Search)
                   df2()}, options = list(dom = 't'))

          df3 <- reactive({
             if (input$Search != "") {     
                   sqldf(paste0("SELECT  *  
                        FROM df WHERE  empName  LIKE '%",input$Search,"%'"))  
               }})                

    output$table3 = DT::renderDataTable({ 
                req(input$Search)
                  df3()}, options = list(dom = 't'))


          df4 <- reactive ({
                   SelectedNames <-stringr::str_c(stringr::str_c("'", input$Search, "'"), collapse = ',')
  

sqldf(paste0("SELECT  empAge, empSalary  
                 FROM df  WHERE  empName IN (",SelectedNames,")  "))
          })     



             output$table4 = DT::renderDataTable({ 
                  req(input$Search)
                 df4()}, options = list(dom = 't')) 
   })
```

I am working with MySQL queries.
In Table 1 the data displayed is the whole employee dataframe , I cannot do that for thousands of rows.

In table 2 I select the  employee names from selectize but display the corresponding IDs .

In Table 3, it only shows one selected value from the selectize.

In table 4, the code allows to query other details from multiple selection of the selectizeInput.

What I am looking for is to be able to select multiple names from selectizeInput but pass the corresponding multiple employee IDs to the Mysql query to get the results like in Table 4.

Thus basically combine the ability to select names but pass the values of the Id column to allow mutiple select in a query.

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified your reactive expression, added the Geo as a initial selection, and moved `selectizeInput` to server side. Try this.

**EDIT:** I have updated the answer to remove initial selection.

```
  ###### updated answer on 8Sep2020
  survey <- data.frame(name = c("Oberösterreich", "Северозападен", "Κύπρος", "Strední Cechy", "Severovýchod", "Praha"),
                       geo = c("AT31", "BG31", "CY00", "CZ02", "CZ05", "CZ01"),
                       population =c(100409314, 54086980, 30961705, 164741605, 156857074, 93166890))
  
  
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      wellPanel(
        uiOutput("regionorgeo")
      )),
    fluidRow(DTOutput('table')),
  )
  
  server = function(input, output, session){
    
    output$regionorgeo <- renderUI({
  
      selectizeInput(
        'Geo',
        label = "Geo Select",
        choices = survey$geo,
        selected=1,
        options = list(
          placeholder = 'Geo Region',
          maxOptions = 1000,
          maxItems = 10,
          searchConjunction = 'and'
        )
      )
      
    })
    
    geonamesdata <- reactive({
      req(input$Geo)
      data <- filter(survey, geo %in% as.character(input$Geo))
      data
    })
    
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(geonamesdata(),
                                        selection = 'single',
                                        options = list(searching = FALSE,pageLength = 10),
                                        server = FALSE, escape = FALSE,rownames= FALSE)
    
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Hello  YBS

Can this be done without the need to have the radio buttons?

Comment: Okay maybe I was not very clear enough. I would like to select the name but pass the corresponding geo to a MySQL query. Reason being, some names with special characters do not return any results in my actual platform. Anyway I can selectize for example **Северозапа** but the value passed to MySQL query is **BG31**  ?

Comment: @Rnoob, in that case, just pass `geonamesdata()$geo` to MySQL  in your code.

Comment: Hello YBS, I have edited my question with new code to try and show what I would wish to achieve with the MySQL queries.. Let Me know if it is more clear